# Unable to send JSON call from Knockout.js view model used in WEB API project

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, knockout-mvc

I'm facing problems while sending AJAX call from one of my Knockout.js model function.

This seems very weird  to me. My Knockout Script looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userinfoViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = ko.observable("0");
        self.First_Name = ko.observable("");
        self.Last_Name = ko.observable("");
        self.Login_Id = Ko.observable("");
        self.Password = ko.observable("");
        self.Role = ko.observable("");

        var user = {
            ID: self.ID,
            First_Name: self.First_Name,
            Last_Name: self.Last_Name,
            Login_Id: self.Login_Id,
            Password: self.Password,
            Role: self.Role
        };

        //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
        self.Users = ko.observableArray([]);

        //Function to Read All Users
        function GetUsers() {
            //Ajax Call Get All Employee Records
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/user",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    self.Users(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
                }
            });
            //Ends Here
        }


        //call GetUsers Ajax call.
        GetUsers();

        //CRUD Operations

        //Function to perform POST (insert User) operation
        self.Create = function () {
            //Ajax call to Insert the User
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/user",
                data: ko.toJSON(User), //Convert the Observable Data into JSON
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Record Added Successfully");
                    self.EmpNo(data.EmpNo);
                    alert("The New Employee Id :" + self.EmpNo());
                    GetEmployees();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
            //Ends Here
        };

        self.update = function () {
            var url = "/api/user/" + self.EmpNo();
            alert(url);
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: url,
                data: ko.toJSON(EmpData),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Record Updated Successfully");
                    GetEmployees();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.status + "<!----!>" + error.statusText);
                }
            });
        };

        //Function to perform DELETE Operation
        self.deleterec = function (user) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/api/EmployeeInfoAPI/" + employee.EmpNo,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
                    GetUser();//Refresh the Table
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
                }
            });
            // alert("Clicked" + employee.EmpNo)
        };


        //Function to Display record to be updated
        self.getselecteduser = function (user) {
            self.ID(user.ID),
            self.First_Name(user.First_Name),
            self.Last_Name(user.Last_Name),
            self.Login_Id(user.Login_Id),
            self.Password(user.Password),
            self.Role(user.Role)
        };
    };

ko.applyBindings(new userinfoViewModel());
    </script>
}
```

and the Underlying HTML i'm using in page looks like -

```
 <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--Bind the TextBoxes in the Table to the observable properties defined into the ViewModel -->
                    <table id="tbldml">
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="ID" data-bind="value: $root.ID" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>First_Name</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="First_Name" data-bind="value: $root.First_Name" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Last_Name</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="Last_Name" data-bind="value: $root.Last_Name" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Login_Id</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="Login_Id" data-bind="value: $root.Login_Id" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="Password" data-bind="value: $root.Password" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Role</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="Role" data-bind="value: $root.Role" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <!--The click binding has the JavaScirpt methods passed to it-->
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind="click :$root.save">Save</button></td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind="click: $root.update">Update</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="FixedContainer">
                        <!--If the lenght of the Users is greater than 0 then visible the Table-->
                        <table data-bind="visible: Users().length>0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>ID</td>
                                    <td>First_Name</td>
                                    <td>Last_Name</td>
                                    <td>Login_Id</td>
                                    <td>Role</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <!--Iterate through an observableArray using foreach-->
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach:  Users">
                                <tr data-bind="click: $root.getselecteduser" id="updtr">
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: ID"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: First_Name"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: Last_Name"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: Login_Id"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: Role"></span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button data-bind="click: $root.deleterec">Delete</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</section>
```

The problem seems very strange though, i guess, the binding is very proper.
My API call URL is something like - ***Http://localhost:1234/api/user***

*Fiddler track :*  I Tried capturing calls through Fiddler but seems like an unknown the *GetUsers()* call from script doesn't get fired at first place. Couldn't spot the issue, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first visible error:

```
self.Login_Id = Ko.observable(""); // must be 'ko'
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting, slowly getting blind now a ways :) but Corrections doesn't help either :(

Comment: Sorry, but further code diving indicates that there are too many errors. Some of them: 1) undefined self.User, 2) undefined self.EmpNo, 3) undefined func GetUser and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your KO model but not applying it.

You need to call ko.applyBindings(new userinfoViewModel());

Comment: arr, I just forgot to mention that piece of code. The call to function was already in place, Just update the question above.

Comment: my ESP is faulty! :)   chances are your KO model may also be blowing up somewhere.  KO can be great at hiding exceptions - best to run in Chrome debugger and break on exceptions: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions - then you can see where it is blowing up.

Comment: JS debugging >> Pain in A. Still digging, thanks for your comments.

Comment: debugging KO can be quite tricky - since a lot of code is executed on the bind inside KO.  your best bet is to start small and slowly add code (or comment out all code).

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD NOT define your single instance user Class INSIDE your model.

What you're doing now is defining a self object inside of your model, with property for a single user.  Then you are essentially pointing a new user object to the self object, where user now has it's own references of the same properties that self does.

Then you are defining another object inside your model that is an array that will hold multiple users.

Take your entirely user class definition out of the model.  It should look like this and NOT be nested in the model:

```
 function User(data){
    self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    self.First_Name = ko.observable(data.First_Name);
    self.Last_Name = ko.observable(data.Last_Name);
    self.Login_Id = Ko.observable(data.Login_Id);
    self.Password = ko.observable(data.Password);
    self.Role = ko.observable(data.Role);
 }
```

then you have your model:

```
var userinfoViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
    self.Users = ko.observableArray([]);

    ...
    in your CREATE function loop through the AJAX response: 
      for(user in ajaxData){
        var newUser = new User(user);
      }
      //then push it onto the Users array
      self.Users.push(newUser);

    ...
    other CRUD functions
    ...        
}
```